# Plain Excel XML to Customised XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, customization

This is my Plain XML File:

```
<Records>
<Record>
<Row A="Banks" B="Amount"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="UOBSGD2" B="50000"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="UOBSGD1" B="75050"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="DBSSGD2" B="55800"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="DBSSGD1" B="14239"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="OCBCSGD1" B="55510"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="OCBCSGD2" B="31714"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="UOBUSD1" B="36471.1"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="UOBUSD2" B="41941.765"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="UOBUSD3" B="48233.02975"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="DBSUSD1" B="55467.9842125"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="OCBCUSD1" B="14239"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="OCBCUSD2" B="16374.85"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="OCBCEUR1" B="45857"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="OCBCEUR2" B="19239"/>
</Record>
<Record>
<Row A="DBSEUR1" B="33510"/>
</Record>
</Records>
```

And this is my Customized XML Template File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<chart caption='Banks' xAxisName='Bank Types' yAxisName='Amount' numberPrefix='$'     <showValues='0' showLegend="1" legendPosition='RIGHT'>

 <styles>

  <definition>
  <style name='CanvasAnim' type='animation' param='_xScale' start= '0' duration='1' />
   </definition>

  <application>
  <apply toObject='Canvas' styles='CanvasAnim' />
  </application>

 </styles>

 <set label='' value=''/>


</chart>
```

This is my question.

The idea is to extract excel XML to insert that into my Customized XML. How and What do you use to program it in such a way like " Plain XML --> Customized XML?

Very sorry for my poor English!!!

Comment: Please add an example of your effort

Comment: What is the result that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello
This is the result I want to achieve...

 <set label='UOBSGD2' value='50000' />

  <set label='UOBSGD1' value='75050' />

Something like that.

Thank you for replying

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your question is. This seems like a *very* simple XSL transformation - where exactly is your difficulty with this?

Comment: Hello @michael.hor257k thank you for replying me.
I'm sorry that my question was not clear.. and English

1) I had to imagine that the excel files will be in a server.

2) The excel files will then become xml ( but the excel file itself will be plain because they are not customized)

3) Then the plain xml will have a customise version... and that is "Customised xml template file"

so, it should be Excel File --> XML --> Customized version of XML --> Fully Furnished XML file.

Should I use XSLT?

From Plain XML to Customised XML Template?

Thank you

Comment: IMHO, to convert the "Plain XML" to a document that matches your template, yes: you should use XSLT for that. You don't need the "Customised XML Template" as such - all of that information should be in the XSLT stylesheet that will be used for the transformation. I cannot say anything about the preceding stages.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint please? @michael.hor257k

Comment: A hint regarding what? I am sorry, but I really have no idea where you are stuck with this.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. But I really need help on how to do the xslt thingee.. you know how to start. but i don't know how to do it. Please show me some samples on how to do. I'll be so grateful... thanks x)

Comment: I suggest you start by doing the tutorial here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/ Then, if you have a **specific** question, by all means post it here

Comment: thank you so much!! and i could read your useful answers too!!! x)

Answer (score 0):

I know the answers now!! it's

```
<xsl:template match="//row">
<xsl:element name="set">

  <xsl:attribute name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Banks" />
  </xsl:attribute>

  <xsl:attribute name="value">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Amount" />
     </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
```

Thanks for helping me, @michael.hor257k